# Stop .cshtml rendering on post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

Say I had this page in ASP.NET RazorPages:

```
@{
    SocketGuild guild = (SocketGuild) ViewData["guild"]
}
<p>The guild has @(guild.Roles.Count) roles.</p>
```

```cs
public async Task OnGet()
{
    ViewData["guild"] = GetGuild();
}

public async Task OnPost()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Post Received");
}
```

When a GET request is received, `ViewData["guild"]` is set by the OnGet handler and the .cshtml renders, allowing the page to be returned.

When a POST request is received the .cshtml file is rendered but a null reference exception is thrown because `ViewData["guild"]` has not been defined. I don't need my .cshtml file to be rendered on a post because my requests are made in the background.

Is it possible to only render the .cshtml file if the OnGet method has been executed? I'm willing to switch to MVC style handlers if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the correct approach in your case will be retaining the actual value through some sort of service so it is accessible inside `Post` request as well:

```
public interface ICacheService
{
    Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}

public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

You should also register the service in your `Startup.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<ICacheService, CacheService>(); // or Scoped depending on your needs
    ...
]
```

Then you can easily use such service with your code:

```
public class SocketGuildModel : PageModel
{
    public ICacheService Cache { get; set; }

    public SocketGuildModel(ICacheService cache)
    {
        Cache = cache;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        Cache.Values["guild"] = GetGuild();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task OnPost()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post Received");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public static SocketGuild GetGuild() => new SocketGuild();
}

public class SocketGuild
{
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

```
@page
@using RazorPagesDemo.Services
@model RazorPagesDemo.Pages.SocketGuildModel

<form method="post" class="mt-3">
    @{
        var guild = (SocketGuild)Model.Cache.Values["guild"];
    }
    <p>The guild has @(guild.Roles.Count) roles.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

That being said, depending on your exact needs you can also add `if ... else ...` logic inside your `.cshtml` file and gate rendering behind the condition  (which might be a `bool` `IsPost` property set during `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods of you `Page Model` for instance).

Comment: Wow, thank you! How exactly does the CacheService value persist between the different requests? In the past, I've experimented by setting a property of the PageModel but it got reset between requests, as if a new instance of the PageModel had been made. Is it because it's registered in Startup.cs?

Comment: Its thanks to the fact that the `Dependency Injection` defines three different lifetime types for services. `Transient` - a new instance is provided each time the object is accessed. `Scoped` - objects remain the same within a single request. `Singleton` - there is always a single instance, even across different requests. This is the best explanation I know: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6Nr7Zman_Y

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I think that for my implementation I will need to make the CacheService class return different values per user, perhaps I could do it neatly by adding some custom middleware. The video was also very useful. Thank you so much!